# post selection and instantaneous communication

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Does post selection lead to instantaneous communication between two points in space?
Below is the scenario:

Take two entangled qubits A and B. Seperate them out in space.
Post select on qubit A to be 1. Immediately qubit B will collapse to 1 irrepective of far apart they are.

Answer (score 0):

True. But there is no way of sending information via this channel, so causality is preserved.